# How can I make a specific part of particles a different color?

Tags: particles, hair

I am modeling a panda teddy bear. However I do not know how To make the different parts like arms,legs,and circles on the face a different color. I’m a noob and would appreciate the help. [image]

Comment: if your particles are hairs, you can use an image texture, paint it, and the hair color will depend of the image texture color underneath

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vertex Pain method. Create the material with the color you want, then where you select object/edit mode find vertex paint. Then just pain over the parts of object you want with that color.  Or you can select faces and add that color to them. This tutorial describes the technique: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lj643VmTsg&t=448s

Edit: I am allso new so take it with a grain of sand :)

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a noob too, so hopefully someone will answer better than I can, but I would think the easiest way to achieve this would be to tell the particle emitter to get its color information from the mesh material. That then requires you to get more detail in your model. You'll have to adjust the mesh to make the edge flow accommodate the circles and curves in the reference image. Instead of a UV sphere, start with a subdivided cube.

If you don't feel like starting over, just select the faces around where each eye would be, inset those faces, and manually adjust them to form a circle. Although if you plan on extruding the snout, that will be very difficult without proper edge flow.

Anyways, then you simply assign a different material to those faces (vertex groups may be helpful), and render the hair from the object materials.

If you plan on making an animation, keep in mind you have a lot of excess geometry in that model, on top of its head and underneath its bum, having started with a UV sphere.

Goodluck to you!

Comment: Thank you for your this. I will consider your solutions. :)